# Is the revoke functionality needs extra api calls to stop the task in queue from execution?

Tags: celery

I have a worker with concurrency set to 1 and a task that goes into infinite loop [for testing]. I submit a task T1 and the worker gets it and goes to work. I submit another task, it gets it and since its busy with T1 still, T2 goes into Queue [rabbitMQ].

I tried T2.revoke()
and revoke(t2.task_id)

And checked with the inspect to see the revoked status. Every thing looks good. But when i restart the worker, it still executes T2.

Is there any thing that needs to be done to suppress the T2 from execution ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use persistent revokes, see [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#worker-persistent-revokes).